# Posting data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a web application in ASP.NET MVC. I use JavaScript, jQuery for different client side problems.

I have this registration form, and upon submitting the user gets an error that there was a mistake while loading the form. I created an `onClick()` event when clicking the submit button, where the button calls function `save()` where the post instructions are. I can't seem to find the problem.

JavaScript code:

```
 $.post("", {
            prijavljeni: $("#vsiPrijavljeni").val(),
            IdTermin: $("#IdTermin").val(),
            Termin: $('#IdTermin :selected').text(),
            IdTecaj: $("#IdTecaj").val(),
            Tecaj: $("#Tecaj").val(),
            Ime: $("#Ime").val(),
            Priimek: $("#Priimek").val(),
            Telefon: $("#Telefon").val(),
            Email: $("#Email").val(),
            Placnik: $.trim($("#Placnik").val()),
            Naslov: $.trim($("#Naslov").val()),
            Posta: $.trim($("#Posta").val()),
            Kraj: $.trim($("#Kraj").val()),
            Zavezanec: $("#Zavezanec").is(":checked"),
            Davcna: $.trim($("#Davcna").val()),
            Soglasje: $("#Soglasje").is(":checked"),
            Voucher: $("#Voucher").is(":checked")

        }
```

HTML markup in my view:

```
<button type="button" id="sbmtButton" onclick="save()" 
        class="button btn btn-default">@DbRes.T("Submit", "Course")</button>
```

Comment: Post the actual error. Your code as shown is not showing anything strange

Comment: "*there was a mistake while loading the form*" - this doesn't sound like a standard javascript validation / MVC error message.  What exactly is generating that message - or is this just a paraphrase/summary, if so, what's the *actual* message.

Comment: Ooops…Something went wrong. Error 500
Sorry for the inconvenience, we're going to fix it up and have things back to normal soon. <-- ERROR.

The error is shown from InternalError.html file. Its a custom error, thats why I didnt post it

Comment: Right, so you got a **500 Internal Server Error** .  The `Exception` that generated the 500 and caused your app to go to the InternalError.html will tell you what the problem is.  Without telling us, we can't tell you.   Note that you should never return an error.html file from an API call and you should always log your exceptions not just cover them up.

Comment: Hi, I found the problem. I did some debugging and found this server error: 

The server response was: 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:InvalidLicenseException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Mailbox ### does not have a valid License.  So after validating the license again it worked. 
Thanks again for the help freedomn-m

Comment: I would suggest you get `onclick="save()"` out of the markup and instead put an event attachment in the JavaScript code.